# Php login form with data from 2 table

Tags: php, forms, authentication

i develop a login form where the user need to fill username & password which i stored in (table1) and also need to enter secret key which i stored in (table2).If username,password & secret key is correct it will display SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE..." whereas if wrong it will display "SORRY... YOU ENTERED WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...". Below are my code for login form and connectivity.php.. for now if i enter correct username,password and correct key it will always display wrong message.

```js
<?php 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'login');
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD',''); 
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
$Username = $_POST['user']; $Password = $_POST['pass'];  $Captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
function SignIn() { session_start(); 

//starting the session for user profile page 
if(!empty($_POST['user'])) 
//checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text 
{

$query = mysql_query("SELECT username.userName, username.pass, ,secret.key where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]' AND key = '$_POST[captcha]'") or die(mysql_error());


$row = mysql_fetch_array($query); 


if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass']) AND !empty($row['captcha'])) 
{ 
$_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass'] = $row['captcha']; 
 echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";
 } 
 else 
 { 
 echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERED WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
  } 
  } 
  } if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { SignIn(); 
  } 
  ?>
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="connectivity.php"> 
User <br><input type="text" name="user" size="40"><br> 
Password <br><input type="password" name="pass" size="40"><br> 
Captcha <br><input type="password" name="captcha" size="40">

<input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log-In"> 
</form>
```

Comment: One too many commas in `username.pass, ,secret.key` and missing `FROM` (what table?) but it's hard to know exactly what's right and what's wrong.

Comment: your query is wrong it would be "SELECT username.userName, username.pass, secret.key where userName" remove , from secret.key

Comment: Do read up on SELECT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username.userName, username.pass, ,secret.key where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]' AND key = '$_POST[captcha]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

with

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$captcha = $_POST['captcha'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT username.userName, username.pass ,username.key from username where userName = '".$user."' AND pass = '".$pass."' AND key = '".$captcha."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

You have done mistakes in your query, before writing your query in script try to make a dummy query and run in your mysql using sql ui or phpmyadmin than implement in your scripts

Comment: Muhammad Ahmed... i've tried your code but still wrong message appeared although the input is correct.. can i contact you through email or   fb?i really2 need help to solve this..

Comment: Yes you can contact me here or my email address, If you need me help.

Comment: can i have your email address? i try to find in your profile but not display email address..

Comment: ahmedzarrar42@gmail.com